# Why am I getting this error "The constructor is undefined"?

Tags: java, constructor, class-design

In Java, getting this error:

```
Error: The constructor MyComplex(MyComplex) is undefined
```

Java Code:

```
public class MyComplex {
    int realPart, imaginaryPart;
    public MyComplex(){
    }
    public MyComplex(int realPart, int imaginaryPart) {
        this.realPart = realPart;
        this.imaginaryPart = imaginaryPart;
    }
    public void setRealPart(int realPart) {
        this.realPart = realPart;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return realPart + " + " + imaginaryPart +"i";
   }
}
public class MyComplexTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyComplex a = new MyComplex(20, 50);
        MyComplex b = new MyComplex(a);        //Error happens here
        b.setRealPart(4);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

The code works fine if I use

```
MyComplex b = a;
```

But I can't change the code in the main method since its a homework on designing the class to run the given method.

Comment: Create a matching constructor.

Comment: What do you expect `new MyComplex(a);` to do? Which constructor do you expect it to run?

Comment: you have not a one parameter constructor.

Comment: You're missing a constructor like `public MyComplex(MyComplex c){...}`

Comment: You need to define yourself "every" constructor in Java. There is no default copy constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

You do not have a constructor that accepts another `MyComplex` (*copy constructor*). You only created constructors that accept:

- No argument, `new MyComplex()`
- Two `int` arguments, `new MyComplex(5, 2)`

---

### Solution

You need to explicitly define constructors that you want to use. Java does not generate such a constructor for you. For example:

```
public MyComplex(MyComplex other) {
    realPart = other.realPart;
    imaginaryPart = other.imaginaryPart;
}
```

Then it will also work.

---

### Notes

In order to increase readability of your code, you should use explicit constructor forwarding for the new *copy constructor* and especially for your *default constructor*.

As an example, right now your default constructor `new MyComplex()` will lead to a complex value of `0 + 0i`. But this can easily be overseen since your code does not clearly indicate that.

With forwarding, the intention is much clearer:

```
public MyComplex() {
    this(0, 0);
}

public MyComplex(MyComplex other) {
    this(other.realPart, other.imaginaryPart);
}
```

Then both will just forward to the explicit constructor that accepts the two `int` values.

Note that the only constructor Java auto-generates for you is the trivial default constructor. That is `public MyComplex() { }` (no arguments - does nothing). And only if you did not write any constructor yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the corresponding (copy) constructor.
So:

```
public MyComplex(MyComplex a){
  realPart = a.realPart;
  imaginaryPart = a.imaginaryPart;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must have an overloaded constructor that accepts an object of type `MyComplex` to get this working.

below is your updated class

```
public class MyComplex {
    int realPart, imaginaryPart;
    public MyComplex(){
    }
    public MyComplex(int realPart, int imaginaryPart) {
        this.realPart = realPart;
        this.imaginaryPart = imaginaryPart;
    }

   public MyComplex(MyComplex mycomplex) {//this is the constructor you need
        this.realPart = mycomplex.realPart;
        this.imaginaryPart = mycomplex.imaginaryPart;
    }

    public void setRealPart(int realPart) {
        this.realPart = realPart;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return realPart + " + " + imaginaryPart +"i";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no constructor declared with MyComplex as argument. You need to declare the below constructor :-

```
 public MyComplex(MyComplex mycomplex) {
    this.realPart = mycomplex.realPart;
    this.imaginaryPart = mycomplex.imaginaryPart;
}
```

Comment: Note that `this` is obsolete in this code. And the name of the variable could be improved to better reflect its job. Idiomatic is `other`.

Answer (score 0):

Because in below line

> MyComplex b = new MyComplex(a);

you are passing a which is of type MyComplex, but in MyComplex class you defined constructor with one parameter whose type is int. please correct your passing parameter.

Comment: This explains the issue but does not attempt to provide a solution to it. Please see [answer], thanks.

Comment: @Zabuza i didn't provide the solution as i don't know his use case, However i mentioned to correct the passing paratmer.